# Error inject toastr in angularjs controller

Tags: css, angularjs, import, alerts, toastr

Hi i want use the toastr notifications for angular js

this: https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr

I have my controller and my index, in mi index y imports all css's and js's for work with my app, but when i tried inject my toastr script in my controller the console show this error

> Unknown provider: toastrProvider <- toastr <- clientController

my index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.min.css" />

    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="resources/angular/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.tpls.js"></script> also try -->



</head>

<body ng-app="app">

     <li><a href="#!client">new client</li>

    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <script src="app/runConfig.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/client.conroller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my controller:

```
(function () {
'use stritct';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('clientController', clientController);

clientController.inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', 'toastr'];

function clientController($rootScope, $scope, $location, toastr) {

}

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, you missed injecting the `toastr` service in to the app module. This is shown in the setup on the github.

`angular.module('app', ['toastr'])`